# Find if two rectangles overlap if one of them was rotated

Tags: python-3.x, overlap, rectangles

I have two rectangles of which one is rotated. I want to check if these two rectangles overlap. What would be the logic for this? I am able to do if they are not rotated but I am unable to get the logic for rotating case.  I have all the four coordinates of both the rectangles and I am using python for this. Can somebody help me, please?
[image: overlap case of non rotated images]

```
 
    def doOverlap(self, l1, d1, l2, d2): 
      
    

        if( ((l2.x <= d1.x) and (l1.y <= d2.y) and (l2.y <= d1.y) and (l1.x <= d2.x)) or ((l1.x <= d2.x) and (l2.y <= d1.y) and (l1.y <= d2.y) and (l2.x <= d1.x))  ): 
            return True
  
   
        return False
```

Comment: how is the rectangle rotated? by a variable angle? or is it allways rotated 90 degrees? anyway you might wanna look into sinus and its friends

Comment: the rectangle is rotated by some variable angle which I do not know. But we can calculate it since we know the all the coordinates of the rectangle

Comment: so if you have all points of the new rectangle, why dont you just check wether one of the lines of the other rectangle shares a point with the first

Comment: But how to check the case where one rectangle lies completely inside the other rectangle?

Comment: u can just look at the points as a vector and then do a simple v1 = v2 and if it comes back as not null